# Jena and the difference between listStatements and listObjectsOfProperty

Tags: jena, semantic-web, foaf

I have a file describing people with the help of FOAF. In Jena I am trying to parse all ages from the profiles and noticed that my listStatements and listObjectsOfProperty gives me different results. I could not easily find any help from the javadocs or other documentation.

I have the following code for querying with listStatments:

```
StmtIterator iter = this.foafmodel.listStatements(
     (Resource) null, 
     this.foafmodel.createProperty("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/age"), 
     (RDFNode) null);
```

And this is the code for listObjectsOfProperty:

```
Property foafAge = this.foafmodel.createProperty("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/age");
NodeIterator iter = this.foafmodel.listObjectsOfProperty(foafAge);
```

In this case listStatements iterator iterates 38 times while the listObjectsOfProperty only 20 times. Can someone explain to me what is the difference between these two implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that your data contains multiple triples with your property `:p` referencing the same object `:o`, like so:

```
:s1 :p :o .
:s2 :p :o .
```

At first glance, it would appear to me that `listObjectsOfProperty` are giving you all individuals that are referenced by your property without duplication. We can confirm this by digging into the implementation that depends on `GraphUtil#listObjects(...)`. The code uses a `Set<Node>` to aggregate all of the objects. As a result, you should only get back a single iteration with the element `:o`.

The other method, `listStatements` should return to you a statement/triple for every time that property is used. In the example model above, you would/should get two results, one for each statements containing `:p`.

Comment: Thanks! I see no duplicates when using listObjectsOfProperty which means when trying to calculate e.g. average age it's the wrong function to use.

Comment: @ksnabb Note that you can use SPARQL to get some answers for those types of questions in Jena (through ARQ). For example, you can use the [average](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_aggAvg) aggregate function as is done in [this example](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#groupby)